# Нужно составить PHP файл для обработки форм заявок с сайта

Tags: php

На сайте 15 форм, как составить php файл, что бы письма приходили на email ?
В html примерно во всех такая форма. Если есть какой-то универсальный шаблон Php для отправки форм буду благодарен.

```
<form id="form2" action="http://my-puff.ru/form1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="text" class="b01 validate[required]" name="nick11" placeholder=" Введите Ваше имя:"/> <br>
<input type="text" id="phone01" class="b02 validate[required]" name="phone11" placeholder=" Введите номер телефона:"/> <br>
<input type="submit" class="but1"  value="Заказать" onclick="yaCounter2.reachGoal('form1'); return true;" style="margin-left:0px;"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item11" value="my-puff.ru.ru - заявка по акции (первый экран)">
</form>
```

Comment: [Работа с формами](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score -1):

Допустим, твоя форма:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Форма обратной связи</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Иван">
Email для связи: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="адрес электронной почты">
Ваше сообщение: <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Тогда создавай php с таким содержанием:

```
<?php
// несколько получателей
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', ';  // обратите внимание на запятую
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// тема письма
$subject = 'Письмо с моего сайта';

// текст письма
$message = 'Пользователь' . $_POST['name'] . ' отправил вам письмо:<br />' . $_POST['message'] . '<br />
Связяться с ним можно по email <a href="mailto:' . $_POST['email'] . '">' . $_POST['email'] . '</a>'
;

// Для отправки HTML-письма должен быть установлен заголовок Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

// Дополнительные заголовки
$headers .= 'To: Иван <Ivan@example.com>' . "\r\n"; // Свое имя и email
$headers .= 'From: '  . $_POST['name'] . '<' . $_POST['email'] . '>' . "\r\n";


// Отправляем
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Или так вариант посложнее:

```
    <?php 
function show_form() 
{ 
?> 
<form action="" method=post> 
<div align="center"> 
              <br />Имя*<br /> 
              <input type="text" name="name" size="40"> 
              <br />Контактный телефон<br /> 
              <input type="text" name="tel" size="40"> 
              <br />Контактный email*<br /> 
              <input type="text" name="email" size="40"> 
              <br />Teма<br /> 
              <input type="text" name="title" size="40"> 
              <br />Сообщение*<br /> 
              <textarea rows="10" name="mess" cols="30"></textarea> 
              <br /><input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit"> 
</div> 
</form> 
* Помечены поля, которые необходимо заполнить 
<? 
} 

function complete_mail() { 
        $_POST['title'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['title'])), 0, 1000); 
        $_POST['mess'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mess'])), 0, 1000000); 
        $_POST['name'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 30); 
        $_POST['tel'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 30); 
        $_POST['email'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 50); 
        // если не заполнено поле "Имя" - показываем ошибку 0 
        if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
             output_err(0); 
        // если неправильно заполнено поле email - показываем ошибку 1 
        if(!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $_POST['email'])) 
             output_err(1); 
        // если не заполнено поле "Сообщение" - показываем ошибку 2 
        if(empty($_POST['mess'])) 
             output_err(2); 
        // создаем наше сообщение 
        $mess = ' 
        Имя отправителя:'.$_POST['name'].' 
        Контактный телефон:'.$_POST['tel'].' 
        Контактный email:'.$_POST['email'].' 
        '.$_POST['mess']; 
        // $to - кому отправляем 
        $to = 'test@test.ru'; 
        // $from - от кого 
        $from='test@test.ru'; 
        mail($to, $_POST['title'], $mess, "From:".$from); 
        echo 'Спасибо! Ваше письмо отправлено.'; 
} 

function output_err($num) 
{ 
    $err[0] = 'ОШИБКА! Не введено имя.'; 
    $err[1] = 'ОШИБКА! Неверно введен e-mail.'; 
    $err[2] = 'ОШИБКА! Не введено сообщение.'; 
    echo '<p>'.$err[$num].'</p>'; 
    show_form(); 
    exit(); 
} 

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) complete_mail(); 
else show_form(); 
?>
```